# Array sorted order recrusion

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, recursion

Below is code for checking whether a given array is sorted. Tried putting in a print command at various stages to understand the code line by line, but to no avail.

```
def sort(a):

    if len(a) == 1:
       return True
    return a[0] <= a[1] and isSorted(a[1:])

a =[127,220,246,277,321,454,534,565,933]

print(sort(a))
```

**Firstly** 
This is throwing an error

> NameError: name 'isSorted' is not defined.

**Second** 
 
The whole code seems like a shorthand. There is no else after if, why is the isSorted only looking from index position 1. This is supposed to a recursive function, can't see one.

Comment: Well your function name is `sort` not `isSorted`

Comment: your code needs editing specially regarding identation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function name is `sort` and not `isSorted`, and when you are writing `print(sort(a))`, you are not returning the array, you are checking if this array is already sorted.

You should do:

```
def sort(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return True
    return a[0] <= a[1] and sort(a[1:])

a =[127,220,246,277,321,454,534,565,933] 
print(sort(a))
```

and the output:

```
True
```

> Second - the whole code seems like a shorthand. There is no else after
>   if, why is the isSorted only looking from index position 1. This is
>   supposed to a recursive function, can't see one.

You don't need an else statement. 
And if starts from index position 1, because it checks if the array is sorted in index 0, and index 1 recursively on the array.
The code go to the last index, until the length is 1, and then it goes back recursively, to check if `a[0] <= a[1]`. You should practice more on recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
def is_sorted(array):
   if not array[1:]:
       return True
   if array[0] <= array[1]:
       return is_sorted(array[1:])
   return False

print(is_sorted([56, 100, 234, 250, 300]))
print(is_sorted([506, 100, 24, 250, 300]))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```